# Is Curve Modifier Axis Alignment working properly?

Tags: modifiers

Can someone help me understand if there's something wrong with the curve modifier axis alignment or if I'm just missing something?
Here are some before/after screenshots:
[image: before]
[image: after]

Could someone please check the attached scene? Is it broken or just my regular dumbness?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want, rotate your mesh 90° on Z so that it's aligned with X, then in the *Array* modifier and in the *Curve* modifier choose the X axis:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I get there are workarounds but would like to know if the fact that it is not working on the Y axis is a bug. Just to be sure before posting has a bug in Blender Issues

Comment: no it was not a bug  ;)